# Unaccurate solve_ivp solution to non-homogeneous ODE (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, differential-equations

Today, I started working for the first time with solve_ivp. My problem is the following:

I have data from an accelerometer and speedometer ( variables a and v in the code), which correspond to the motion data of a body under a fluid. The governing equation of motion is:

[image: eq1]

Summarizing, what I want to do is:

1. Obtaining an array with the Force wrt time (easy)
2. Since a is the derivative of v, and we now have a variable F depending on time, I want to solve the differential equation:

[image: eq2]

and compare the recovered velocity with the original measured one.

##### My attempt:

I am using solve_ivp for this, and this is my code (I assumed that m=1, so I omited it in the calculations):

```
def obtainF(self, v, a):
    return(a + self.coef * v**2)


def eqMot(self, t, y, F, coef):
    return(F[t] - coef*y*y)

def diffSolver(self, F): 

    t = linspace(0,len(F)-1,len(F))

    y0 = [0.0]
    p = [F, self.coef]

    sol = solve_ivp(self.eqMot, [0, len(F)-1], y0, args = p, t_eval=t)

    return(sol.y[0])
```

(the code is pretty much self-explainatory). Code updated afterDavidJ answer (the issue remains)

The original acceleration and velocity are pretty much sinusoids with a small low-frequency offset. They are even low-pass filtered in advance in order to avoid any conflict with the solver.

##### The issue:

The original and computed velocities do not mach. Not only that, but the missmatch seems to decrease when increasing 'coef'.

Obtained plot for 'coef' = 0.2:

[image: plot1]

And, here, for 'coef' = 1.5:

[image: plot2]

I am not understanding the origin of the issue. Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Why does your initial condition have two components? `self.eqMot` depends on `v` rather than `y` and the system is first-order

Comment: @DavidJ both velocity and acceleration are 0 at t=0, isn't it?

Comment: You don't need `y` - `v` is your only state variable. Unless you what to implicitly integrate `v` as well using the Ivp solver, rather than using quadrature afterwards

Comment: I can replace that line with y0 = [0], but the result is still the same

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is `F`?  In the description, you write `F(t)`, which suggests that `F` is a known function of the continuous time variable t, but in the code, you write `F[t]`, which doesn't make sense, because that is not how you call a function, and if `F` is actually an array, you can't index it with a floating point value.

Comment: Your equation is right only for positive velocity, in general the friction term is `coeff*norm(v)*v` with the euclidean norm or absolute value in one dimension.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser If you prefer, you can define F as def F(self, v, a, t):
    return(a[t] + self.coef * v[t]**2) It does not change the overall result

Comment: @LutzLehmann True! Forgot to note that v is always positive here

Comment: @user3141592 but your red curve is negative for a short period after the initial condition.

Comment: The problem could just be incompatible delays in the measurement of v and a. This then results in a delay in the numerical solution that is larger for smaller friction. In the case of small friction the maxima of the numerical solution are all on the downswings of the measured data. I'm not sure if this is an explanation or a speculative description. How compatible are the v and a sequences, are the divided differences of v in the ballpark of a? (Use means of the pairs for higher accuracy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem. As @LutzLehmann suggested in a comment, since I was taking the velocity measurements from one sensor and the acceleration data from a different one, even though at a first glance the later seemed the derivative of the former, in a sample-by-sample it turned out that there were significant differences between de (manually computed) derivative of speed and accel.

I solved it by mixing both sources of data with a complementary filter and working with the resulting velocity vector, differentiating it afterwards.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The system presented is first-order. I believe you are trying to solve the following.

```
def obtainF(self, v, a):
    return(a + self.coef * v * v)


def eqMot(self, t, v, F, coef):
    # indexing `F` with a float `t` can lead to problems. 
    # Use interpolation of `F` to ensure this evaluates correctly.
    return(F(t) - coef * v * v)

def diffSolver(self, F): 

    t = linspace(0.0,len(F)-1.0,len(F))

    y0 = [0.0]
    # According to the API doc `args` should be a tuple
    p = (F, self.coef)

    sol = solve_ivp(self.eqMot, [0.0, len(F)-1.0], y0, args = p, t_eval=t)

    v_new = sol.y

    return v_new
```

It appears you're mixing object-oriented and functional programming styles too. Consider which one makes more sense and implement consistently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code is cleaner and more correct now, but the issue unfortunately persists. Regarding my programming styles, I'll take note - thanks for telling me!

Comment: Does the value of `eqMot(0.0, y0, F, coef)` equal `F[0]`. In your plots this equality clearly does not hold.

Comment: eqMot(0.0, y0, F, coef) should not equal F[0] but rather a[0]

Comment: Your initial condition is `v=0`, hence `a[0] = F[0]`